# Keyboard and mouse doesn't work after accidental deletion of xorg.conf.d

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, mouse

I accidentally deleted the `xorg.conf.d` folder. Now my mouse, keyboard, touchpad aren't working, and I am stuck on login screen.

Also booting with older kernels doesn't work. However, the keyboard works in bios and grub. I don't have a backup, and there is too much to lose.

Grub and dpkg did not help.

Comment: Login to a console (or with ssh) and reinstall the package containing `xorg.conf.d`.  With luck that should restore _some_ X functionality.

Comment: I am currently in recovery / root how to connect to wifi from terminal?

Comment: @AtyoumUstainof Your wifi settings are likely in your home directory, and the program named NetworkManager uses your wifi. It is a GUI software, so you can't do it from command line. The simplest solution would be that putting your laptop to a wired connection. However, I suggest to ask this as a different question - so you will get more likely much better answers, as mine was in this comment.

Comment: @peterh Thank you for your time i figured it out. after i stopped waisting time trying to connect to Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to connect to wi-fi or any other Internet connection. So i plugged in my bootable thub drive and used it's file manager to locate files on a bootable usb, then i just copied and pasted them into /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.dto my hd (which was shown as external drive ) and everything was working fine after. (You should open your hd as root in order to be able to paste files there) This solution worked for me. hope no one repeats my mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

The whole path of your `xorg.conf.d` was likely `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. I found it by running the `locate xorg.conf.d` command on my own Linux system.

First, you have to find out, which packages used this directory. You can do it with the

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

command. My result is:

```
# dpkg -S /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
xserver-xorg-input-libinput, xserver-xorg-input-wacom, xserver-xorg-input-evdev, xserver-xorg-input-synaptics, xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu, xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse, xserver-xorg-core: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

You can simply reinstall these packages by the command

```
apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-core
```